# Can not compiler Java 10 feature

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, javac

I am using a Java 10 API in my source code, when I try to compiler this code with maven and idea, it throws an error:

```java
// I use this Java 10 API
URLDecoder.decode(query, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

```
// throw this error
Error:(10, 73) java: incompatible types: java.nio.charset.Charset cannot be converted to java.lang.String
```

My Env:

- JDK 10
- maven: 3.6
- IDEA

I was fine if I remove this API.

And I do follow things:

1. add compiler option to pom

```xml
 <maven.compiler.target>10</maven.compiler.target>
 <maven.compiler.source>10</maven.compiler.source>
```

2. change IDEA language level to java10

   File -> Project Struct -> Module -> Language Level

Above two do not work.

Comment: try this: `StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()`

Comment: If you solve this problem, please share with me. Because I still didn't solve this since two days ago.

Comment: I solved with this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55980478/10995103 Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

I've created a [sample project](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/3496p5on461ujv0/Decoder.zip) according to your description and cannot reproduce the problem.

It compiles without errors in both [IntelliJ IDEA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9YRV.png) and in the [command line Maven](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HB39H.png).

If the issue is still reproducible for you, please [contact support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new) with the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) attached and also specify your IntelliJ IDEA version.

Comment: somehow it works for me on local as well but fails in a pipeline environment

Comment: @fireball.1 : I had the same issue - you might not have the same JDK locally.
I used https://hub.docker.com/_/maven to run maven locally in the same version as used in GitHub Actions.
https://github.com/nektos/act is your friend if you want to test GitHub Actions locally.